# Wordpress - How to call php variable in functions.php(backend) and retrieve it at the front end using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, echo

I am trying to call a country API at the backend and access it from the front end so that the access key is not visible to the public.

I tried using this method but it prints the exact string of the php echo.
The $strCountry is defined at Wordpress backend (functions.php) and it is working there.

```
<script>
var countryCode = "<?php echo $strCountry ?>"; 
alert(countryCode);

</script>
```

[image]

I am not sure if this has something to do with Wordpress or something else is going on. Considering I could not change the file extension to .php and it is most probably in .html extension.
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Need more information about how you're outputting your script. Is your script being output by a PHP file? (I'm guessing not.)

Comment: So the variable $strCountry is defined in a php file. And yes you are right, the above script is in a HTML file.

Comment: The script needs to be processed by mod_php (or another PHP SAPI) on the server for the PHP code in it to work. Usually this will mean that the script needs to have a name ending in ".php" (though it's possible to configure your server to use other criteria).